# No page numbering is appearing when using fancy header and subfile packages?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I know this topic is the subject of numerous posts on this forum. I have read through them, but I don't really understand the answers and they haven't been working for me. Furthermore, I am also using the `subfile` package, so I am not sure if that complicates matters.

Please note, I am set on using subfiles and I have previously made all the page numbering work, but I no longer have access to that code so I cannot quite find what I need to do.

**Example**:

Here is a quick example that I just made up: (to be run in Overleaf). I know there are lots of redundant packages, but I have just left them all in so I don't need to worry about issues appearing when I add them back in...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% set font  
\usepackage{fontspec}   
\setsansfont{Arial}     
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}   %overrides automatic normalFont from \begin{document}

% setting the line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

% set margins
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 20mm]{geometry}   % sets all margins to 20mm

% for figures 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\captionsetup{font=small} 
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf} %,textfont=it}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf}

% for tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% for paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{parskip}
%\setlength{\parskip}{0.8em}

% to get degree symbol
\usepackage{textcomp}
% for arrows and therefore
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

% to exclude subsubsections from ToC
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

% for cross referencing files
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}       % allow multilines in tables

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% load this last
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}

\begin{titlepage}

    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{4cm}
        \begin{center}
            \Large
            \textbf{TITLES}
        \end{center}
        
        \vspace{1cm}
        RANDOM TITLE WORDS HERE       
        \vspace{1.5cm}
        
        \textbf{AUTHOR NAME HERE}
        \vfill
        
        COLLEGE REPORT TESTER \\
        
    \end{center}                
\end{titlepage}

\singlespacing
\thispagestyle{empty}   % to remove the line from ToC pg. 1
\tableofcontents
%\thispagestyle{empty}   % to remove the line from ToC pg. 2
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

\doublespacing
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}    % start page count at 1 instead of 2
\subfile{Abstract}

\clearpage
\newpage
\subfile{TESTER}


\end{document}
```

In the 'Abstract.tex' file, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[./main.tex]{subfiles}

\pagestyle{fancy}
%\chead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\section{Abstract}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

and in the 'TESTER.tex' file I have:

```
\documentclass[./main.tex]{subfiles}

\pagestyle{fancy}
%\chead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

However, **there are no page numbers appearing at the bottom of the pages**. The table of contents is able to detect the page numbers correctly, but I cannot understand why they won't appear.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I have spent a decent amount of time trying to fix this to no avail.

Comment: With `\fancyhf{}` you clear all header and footer field, so also the `cfoot` field that should contains the page number.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum - thanks for your response! Wow, that does actually make the page numbers appear again. However, now that `\fancyhf{}` has been removed, the headers of the page have automatically been filled with the chapter name (top left) and the page number and section/subsection name (top right). How can I remove those? Thanks

Comment: Use `\fancyhead{}` to clear only the headers.

Comment: Many thanks @PietervanOostrum! That does indeed work and now the page numbering works.